# Какой шанс, что С и C окажутся на одной клавише?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

Дано.
Есть 26 символов английского алфавита. Располагаем их на клавиатуре из 33 клавиш не важно в какой последовательности.

Далее нам дано 33 символа кириллического алфавита. Известно, что 12 из них совпадают (практически) в начертании `А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х` с английскими. Случайным образом располагаем их на клавиатуре.

Как вычислить шанс того, что хотя бы любая одна пара сходных символов  (например, `C` и `С`) окажется на одной клавише? А две пары, три и так далее?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101473/discussion-on-question-by-4per------c----).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Установим кириллические буквы в каком-нибудь порядке, пронумеруем от 1 до 33.
Пронумеруем латинские буквы от 1 до 26. Их нужно расставить по позициям от 1 до 33. Число способов сделать это равно (это называется [число размещений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

```
      33!       33!
N = --------  = --- = 1722880479922993352285356032000000
    (33-26)!     7!
```

Обозначим через `g(i)` число способов поставить наши 26 латинских символов по 33 кириллическим так, чтобы совпадали **хотя бы** символы от `1` до `i`. Это число равно

```
        (33-i)!  
g(i) = -------- 
          7!
```

Поясню: то есть `26-i` буквы мы можем поставить по `33-i` позициям:

```
      (33-i)!         (33-i)!
------------------ =  -------
((33-i) - (26-i))!       7!
```

Теперь всё это нужно умножить на [число сочетаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) из `12` по `i`, чтобы учесть все возможные `i` букв из 12-ти:

```
                                   / 12 \ 
f(i) = g(i)*binomial(12,i) = g(i)*|      |
                                   \  i /
```

Теперь пользуемся формулой включения-исключения для определения того, сколько у нас комбинаций не имеют ни одного совпадения:

```
N - f(1) + f(2) - f(3) ... = 1193302430098089637938828023808000
(сумма идёт до 12)
```

То есть из общего числа всех возможных расстановок вычитаем те, у которых минимум одно совпадение, но мы когда их считали путём умножения на число сочетаний, также учли совпадения 2-х, 3-х и т. д. букв по нескольку раз, их нужно прибавить обратно. Ну и так далее, читайте теорию [по ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Ну вот, мы знаем число вариантов, когда совпадений нет, и число всех вариантов. Делим одно на другое:

```
0.6926205526174549408291876419168263634...
```

Теперь давайте считать число комбинаций, когда минимум одно совпадение. Это будет

```
f(1) - f(2) + ... = 529578049824903714346528008192000
```

Всё по той же формуле включения исключения.
Делим это число на `N` получаем:

```
0.307379447382545059170812358083173636622...
```

Далее хотим минимум два совпадения:

```
f(2) - f(3) + f(4) - ... = 96923942874366595575419639808000
```

и вероятность

```
0.05625691625381857719282400555318999974
```

Ну и так далее:

```
0 :: 0.6926205526174549408291876419168263634...
1 :: 0.307379447382545059170812358083173636622...
2 :: 0.05625691625381857719282400555318999974...
3 :: 0.006243083746181422807175994446810000...
4 :: 0.0004773463613454589132541130800...
5 :: 0.0000266858967190572157781449844444...
6 :: 0.0000011227795879505706512209777...
7 :: 3.59e-8
8 :: 8.687e-10
9 :: 1.55e-11
10:: 1.949e-13
11:: 1.54e-15
12 :: 5.88e-18
```

Кто хочет плюсовать мой ответ, плюсуйте также ответ @Harry, с его помощью я убедился в правильности вычислений.

Comment: Пока что-то не врублюсь в g(i). 26-i по 33-i позициям - понятно, но почему именно i по i позициям? А если они станут так, что ни одна не станет на свое место? Все до и все после (начиная от *"Теперь пользуемся формулой включения-исключения") понятно, но эти несколько абзацев что-то понять не удается...

Comment: @Harry , `g(i)` - это когда мы поставили `1` на место `№1`, `2` на место `№2` и так далее, то есть поставили первые `i` букв именно на свои места (на свой первые `i` мест), они НЕ могут не попасть, потому что мы их насильно поставили на свои места. То это это не перестановки `i` элементов по `i`, а именно жёсткая их установка друг на друга по их порядку.

Comment: А, кажется, врубился. И тогда плевать, попадает ли что-то еще на свои места (то, что меня все время сбивало с толку, когда я пробовал формулы выводить...)

Answer (score 14):

Прямое решение через метод включения-исключения уже предложено @Zealint.

Можно также почти по [нелегкому] пути разложения на *несовместные* события, А именно вычислить вероятности того, что *ровно* одна буква совпадет, *ровно* две буквы совпадут и т.д. до вероятности совпадения *ровно* двенадцати букв. Тогда искомая вероятность ("хотя бы одна") будет равна сумме вероятностей этих несовместных событий.

Без потери общности можно полагать, что порядок русских букв на клавишах уже зафиксирован. И нам остается лишь посчитать интересующие нас расположения букв латинского алфавита. Будем считать, что мы дополнили латинский алфавит до 33 букв 7 дополнительными пробелами. "Нерусские" символы латинского алфавита и пробелы будем вместе называть *свободными* буквами (их вместе 21). При этом надо помнить о том, что все дополняющие пробелы одинаковы, и перестановки, отличающиеся только "порядком пробелов", считаются одинаковыми.

Пусть у нас есть "каноническая" перестановка

```
AВЕКМНОРСТУХБГДЁЖЗИЙЛПФЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
ABEKMHOPCTYXDFGIJLNQRSUVWZ.......
            |<---------->|---------- "нерусские" буквы (14)
                          |<--->|--- пробелы (7)
            |<----------------->|--- свободные буквы (21)
```

Будем говорить, что в этой перестановке все латинские буквы стоят на *своих* местах.

Чему же равно количество перестановок, в которых на своем месте находится буква `A` и *только* буква `A`?

Воспользуемся [субфакториалом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB), который даст нам количество [*беспорядков*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)) (перестановок, в которых ни один элемент не стоит на *своем* месте) и смело навскидку предположим, что ответ равен **!32**. Это, конечно же, неверное предположение, потому что

1. Мы совсем не хотим запрещать *свободным* буквам попадать на любые места в перестановке, в том числе на *свои*. То есть на 21 букву требование "беспорядка" распространяться не должно.
2. Мы должны учесть, что перестановки, отличающиеся только "порядком пробелов", считаются одинаковыми.

Чтобы учесть первый пункт, нам необходимо к **!32** добавить величину

**C<sub>21</sub><sup>1</sup> * !31 + C<sub>21</sub><sup>2</sup> * !30 + ... + C<sub>21</sub><sup>21</sup> * !11**

где **C<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>** - биномиальный коэффициент.

Каждое слагаемое в этой сумме - это фактически разрешение определенному подмножеству *свободных* букв (множитель **C<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>**) занять *свое* место, при условии, что все остальные буквы на свои места не попадут (множитель c субфакториалом). (Здесь мы фактически тоже суммируем несовместные события.)

Чтобы учесть второй пункт, нам нужно просто разделить результат на **7!**.

В более общих терминах, можно записать это все в виде формулы количества *обобщенных беспорядков*

**D(d, f, b) = (!d + C<sub>f+b</sub><sup>1</sup> !(d+f+b-1) + C<sub>f+b</sub><sup>2</sup> !(d+f+b-2) + ... + C<sub>f+b</sub><sup>f+b</sup> !d) / b!**

где **d** - количество элементов, которым *запрещается* попадать на *свои* места, **f** - количество элементов, которые *могут* попадать на *свои* места и порядок которых *важен* (это "нерусские" буквы), и **b** - количество элементов, которые могут попадать на *свои* места и порядок которых *не важен* (это пробелы).

Например, количество перестановок, в которых на своем месте находится буква `A` и только буква `A` равно **D(11, 14, 7)**.

Пользуясь этой формулой мы можем запросто получить ответ исходной задачи.

Количество перестановок, где *ровно* 1 буква попадает на свое место равно

**C<sub>12</sub><sup>1</sup> D(11, 14, 7) = 442631885946180412726163791872000**

Количество перестановок, где *ровно* 2 буквы попадают на свое место равно

**C<sub>12</sub><sup>2</sup> D(10, 14, 7) = 77704405449651224014347472896000**

и так далее

**C<sub>12</sub><sup>3</sup> D(9, 14, 7) = 8546267921601441849709731840000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>4</sup> D(8, 14, 7) = 656661796031872805799905280000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>5</sup> D(7, 14, 7) = 37182147735786558729928704000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>6</sup> D(6, 14, 7) = 1593122841495474140307456000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>7</sup> D(5, 14, 7) = 52122234005692866183168000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>8</sup> D(4, 14, 7) = 1294472498870414223360000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>9</sup> D(3, 14, 7) = 23842642421965086720000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>10</sup> D(2, 14, 7) = 309769248191090688000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>11</sup> D(1, 14, 7) = 
2554547108585472000

     C<sub>12</sub><sup>12</sup> D(0, 14, 7) = 10137091700736000**

Последняя величина ожидаемо равна **21! / 7!**. А сумма всех этих величин ожидаемо равна **529578049824903714346528008192000** - вы уже видели это значение в ответе @Zealint.

Соответственно получаем вероятности несовместных событий

```
Ровно 1: 0.256914
Ровно 2: 0.0451014
Ровно 3: 0.00496045
Ровно 4: 0.000381142
Ровно 5: 2.15814e-05
Ровно 6: 9.24686e-07
Ровно 7: 3.0253e-08
Ровно 8: 7.51342e-10
Ровно 9: 1.38388e-11
Ровно 10: 1.79797e-13
Ровно 11: 1.48272e-15
Ровно 12: 5.8838e-18
```

и финальную вероятность для случая "хотя бы одна"

```
0.307379
```

Прелесть решения с вероятностями таких несовместных событий заключается в том, что теперь вы, например, с легкостью можете дать ответ на вопрос о том, какова вероятность того, что количество совпавших букв будет *нечетным*. Или о том, какова вероятность того, что количество совпавших букв *лежать между 4 и 7*. И т.д и т.п.

P.S. Внимательный читатель заметит, что и здесь спрятан метод включения-исключения - из-за формулы вычисления количества беспорядков (субфакториала) очевидным образом торчат уши этого метода.

Comment: Отличный подход!

Comment: *"Или о том, какова вероятность того, что количество совпавших букв лежать между 4 и 7."* - это как раз даже легче при методе включения-исключения :)

Comment: Ой. [Попалось](https://www.facebook.com/groups/168135496554471/permalink/2831250286909632/), что обозначение !n - "это просто сумма факториалов всех натуральных чисел до n".

Comment: @Harry: Диалектов хватает. Видимо, есть и такой... Как пишет Вольфрам, (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftFactorial.html) "К сожалению, тот же термин и запись также используются для обозначения факториальной суммы". То есть не только запись, но и термин *левый факториал* является неоднозначным. Именно поэтому в педантичном изложении важно определять используемую символику и понятия.

Comment: Кнут в "Конкретной математике" писал почти по-испански :) - `¡n` :)

Answer (score 13):

Вобщем, в теории я зашился, но за эксперимент вроде бы готов ответить :) Так что кто будет теорию писать - если она у вас будет существенно не сходиться с моими результатами, то вам нужно будет серьезно пояснять, где я ошибся...

По миллиарду вычислительных экспериментов распределение такое -

```
 0:  0.6926332
 1:  0.2569070   хотя бы :) 0.3073668
 2:  0.0450958   хотя бы :) 0.0504598
 3:  0.0049600   хотя бы :) 0.0053640
 4:  0.0003817   хотя бы :) 0.0004040
 5:  0.0000214   хотя бы :) 0.0000223
 6:  0.0000009
 7:  0.0000000
 8:  0.0000000
```

Ну, понятно, что и дальше почти нули :)

Comment: Поздравляю! Первое число почти точно верное :) `0.69262055261745` Но так лень писать точный ответ... Что делать?

Comment: Вот как это точно считается (только первое число)
`sum { (-1)^i*(33-i)!*binomial(12, i), i = 0 .. 12 } / 33!`

Comment: @Zealint Что делать, что делать... Не лениться! :)

Comment: Обожди, давай сначала сверим остальные ответы. Мне кажется, дальше ты не то считал: во второй строке нужно считать вероятность ХОТЯ БЫ одного совпадения (по задаче автора). Берём одну букву, фиксируем. Остаётся `32!/7!*12` вариантов поставить остальные. Но мы посчитали лишние двойные совпадения по нескольку раз. Вычитаем их `31!/7! * binom(12,2)`. Затем прибавляем тройные обратно и т. д. У меня получилось `0.30737944738254505917...`

Comment: А следующая строка: `0.056256916253818577...`

Comment: @Zealint Нет, я считал строго одного, двух и так далее - так что надо просто просуммировать :)

Comment: Ну просуммируй, пожалуйста, и добавь, а я пишу ответ уже теоретический.

Comment: Ну вот, вроде так...

Comment: благодарю. Худо-бедно, совпадает с точными данными, значит всё хорошо.

Comment: @Harry, а вы эксперимент проводили с участием значения 26 или как писали в комментариях про 12 первых элементов?

Comment: Я написал быстрый вариант с 12, потом написал медленную полную имитацию разбрасывания 26 букв. Они на 1000 дали одинаковые результаты. После чего я с чистой совестью отключил медленный способ и запустил быстрый :)

Comment: тогда в теоретических ответах чего-то не хватает, они-то 26 не игнорируют, не сокращают